# Button is not clicked while running script in Eclipse

Tags: java, selenium, button, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Web driver for learning automation.
When running the script in eclipse[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q16wn.png) a button is not being clicked and element not found error is showing. When I inspected the element with firebug I found that it is showing as an onclick function (image attached). My script is failing every time when it comes to clicking the button.

Can anyone help please?

**Here is my code**

```
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create a New Test")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("testing_name")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("testing_name")).sendKeys("automated test26");
    driver.findElement(By.id("start_url")).clear();


driver.findElement(By.id("start_url")).sendKeys("https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/selenium-how-to-identify-the-button-webelement");
        driver.findElement(By.id("test_type_save_selection")).click();


    driver.findElement(By.name("Run Test")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("logout")).click();
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.name("Run Test")).click();                                                    //unable to click this button

Comment: test_type_save_selection" where is this ID

Comment: Share the URL
??

Comment: can you post the error message

Comment: The "a" element haven't the Name property, it have the Title property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use xpath as I saw there is no name property in HTML. Also use Wait till element to be clickable.

Try this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create a New Test")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("testing_name")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("testing_name")).sendKeys("automated test26");
driver.findElement(By.id("start_url")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("start_url")).sendKeys("https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/selenium-how-to-identify-the-button-webelement");
driver.findElement(By.id("test_type_save_selection")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);   
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(@title, 'Run Test')] ")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@title, 'Run Test')]")).click();   
driver.findElement(By.linkText("logout")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below XPath :

```
//*[contains(@title, 'Run Test')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the image, and I noticed that the title is **Run Test - Opens dialog** and not **Run Test**.

Try this following line:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title, 'Run Test - Opens dialog')]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks everyone who responded ,I'll try these and get back to you guys.